# Q: Loop over all tokens in the body of a macro

Tags: macros, debugging, token-lists

I am looking for TeX-code that loops over all tokens in a macro definition.
`\meaning` transforms everything to "other" (catcode 12) characters and is thus not directly suited (with or without `\@strip@prefix`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Loop over *and do what* with each token?

Comment: You can have a look at `\tl_show_analysis:n` of `expl3`

Comment: Does the loop need to keep track of spaces & braces, as well?

Comment: No, just other macros.

Comment: it isn't clear what you want the loop to do, given `\def\zz{ a {xyz}b}`  do you want to iterate over space,a,space,lbrace,x,y,z,rbrace,b  or iterate over a, {xyz}, b or ...

Comment: Tokens in \zz are: <space>, a, {xyz}, b.
Ultimately, I want to list all macros in the definition of \zz.

Comment: that isn't what tex means by token (which would be space,a,space,lbrace,x,y,z,rbrace,b)  to tex `{abc}` is 5 tokens

Answer (score 2):

In response to the OP comment, "Ultimately, I want to list all macros in the definition of `\zz`."

EDIT: I reformulated my answer with the `tokcycle` package because I found the original answer from 3.5 years ago did not handle the case well if control sequences were embedded down inside groups inside the macro.  Now, nested groups pose no challenge to the task.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\looptokens[1]{\expandafter\looptokensaux\expandafter{#1}{#1}}
\newcommand\looptokensaux[2]{%
  The macro \detokenize{#2}contains these control sequences:
  \tokcycle{}{\processtoks{##1}}{\detokenize{##1}}{}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\def\zz{What \textit{\textsc{macros like \today}} are contained 
  \textbf{in this argument} \relax??}
\looptokens{\zz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\string#1` would not add the space that `\detokenize{#1}` adds.

Comment: @Manuel if that is an issue...

Answer (score 2):

Poor man's way. If I understand correctly you want *all* macros encountered in the meaning (even within braces).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\fetchsubmacros#1{\def\fsm@temp{#1}\expandafter\fsm@i\meaning\fsm@temp~}
\catcode`& 7
\def\fsm@i#1->#2~%
   {\begingroup\ttfamily\catcode`\{=9 \catcode`\}=9 \everyeof{&}%
    \makeatletter\scantokens{\fsm@ii#2}}
\def\fsm@ii#1{\ifx&#1\endgroup\expandafter\@gobbletwo\fi\fsm@iii#1}
\catcode`& 4
\def\fsm@iii#1{\ifcat\relax\noexpand#1Found: \string#1\par\fi\fsm@ii}
\makeatother                       

\begin{document}


\fetchsubmacros{What \textit{\foo macros} are \bar contained \textbf{in \emph{this argument}} \relax??}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this does not work with all those nasty LaTeX3 macros using `_` and `:`in their names... it is geared towards finding traditional LaTeX2e macros using only possibly @ as special letter. (it skips active characters i.e. `~` or the Babel shorthands)

Comment: Yep! This is it.
I can build my stuff on it. Seems like I do not (yet) have those `nasty' LaTeX3 macros in my own packages. ;)

Thank you!

Comment: in case some macros like `\tl_show_analysis:n` are visible in meaning, my code will say: `Found \tl` because the `\scantokens` will be done with `_` having its usual catcode, not letter catcode. If you know in advance things like this occur (visibly, not hidden in sub-macros) in your analysed macro, you could try `\ExplSyntaxOn` next to the  `\makeatletter` before the `\scantokens` (not tested...). Some non-LaTeX3 packages do use other special letters than `@`, e.g. my own `xint` uses `_`, `:`, and even `?` as letters.