# Creating macro cross references

Tags: macros, debugging

Is there any tool that allows me to analyze/see/display macro dependencies?

To be clear:  After

```
\def\a{\b\c}
\def\b{\x\c}
```

I'd like to get that `\a` uses `\b` and `\c` and that `\b` uses `\x` and `\c`, best nicely displayed.  And to make me entirely happy: the tool should also tell me that `\a` was defined in file X at line Y...

Comment: Obviously, this question is related to your other one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393325/q-loop-over-all-tokens-in-the-body-of-a-macro

Answer (score 1):

Slightly editing my answer to your other related question, [Q: Loop over all tokens in the body of a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393325/q-loop-over-all-tokens-in-the-body-of-a-macro).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\let\enddependency\relax
\let\test\relax
\newcommand\dependency[1]{The macro \string#1 contains these dependencies:%
  \expandafter\dependencyaux#1\enddependency\par}
\def\dependencyaux#1#2\enddependency{%
  \ifcat\relax\noexpand#1 \string#1\fi
  \ifx\enddependency#2\else\dependencyaux#2\enddependency\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\def\a{ blah \b de-blah-blah \c}
\def\b{\x{\c}}
\dependency{\a}
\dependency{\b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good. But the macros may also have arguments.  So what about \def\c#1{\y{#1}\z}

Comment: My Q is solved in my other post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393325/q-loop-over-all-tokens-in-the-body-of-a-macro?noredirect=1#comment977297_393325.

Thanks all!